# How to define horizontal axis in MatPlotLib without a deprecation error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a single chart, a double y-axis and single x-axis MatPlotLib chart, working in python but I am getting a deprecation error from the following "ax=" line

```
plt.clf()   
fig = plt.figure(1, (10, 4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)   # this is the line that generates a deprecation error
```

MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.

Trying this next line creates the same

```
ax=plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

I also get the error:

```
"UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail"
```

when I change this "ax =" line to the following line which was recommended by the MatPlotLib documentation at https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-secondary-axis-py

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)
```

My question is: I realize I am missing something simple but what is the correct way to create this ax horizontal axis definition?

Comment: Your code works without warning nor error for me. It feels like the issue is relate to something else (like multithreading).

Comment: Apart from that, the recommended way is to replace both `plt.figure()` and `fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)` by `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. [Pyplot vs Object Oriented Interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/)

Comment: @JohanC when you say to replace with fig, ax - do you have any ideas on how would I fit all of my parameters into a combined expression.? Using the (1, 1, 1) and (1, (10, 4))

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))`? There are many [many more parameters](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html).